# How to detect html table and add some unique id with PHP?

Tags: php

Data I have from database `$template['content']` (input) :

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to process it into this (output) :

```
<div id="area_912">    
<table id="table_912" contenteditable="true">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="area_311">        
<table id="table_311" contenteditable="true">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and than select all between `div` each id and put it into an array like this :

```
$table = array('area_912' => '<div id="area_912">    
<table id="table_912" contenteditable="true">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>',
'area_311' => '<div id="area_311">        
<table id="table_311" contenteditable="true">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>');
```

And update the `content` with table replaced by `{{input_area_xxx}}`.
To detect html table tag, I instantly using `str_replace("<table>","<table contenteditable="true">",$template['content']);` but I can't imagine how to put an unique id on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the tables and assign id and some content to them individually

```
$template      = $template['content'];
$noOpeningTags = str_replace('<table>', '', $template);
$noClosingTags = str_replace('</table>', '', $noOpeningTags);
$tableContents = explode("\n\n", $noClosingTags);
$newTables     = [];

foreach ($tableContents as $tableContent) {
    $randId = rand();

    $newTables["area_$randId"] = <<<AREA
        <div id="area_$randId" contenteditable="true">
            <table id="table_$randId">
                $tableContent
            </table>
        </div>
    AREA;
}

var_dump($newTables);
```

Comment: I modify your code and it's solved. thanks https://pastebin.com/jBe5RFTP